# boost mingw vs cygwin support

Tags: boost, mingw, bitcoin, msys

**Question**
As I understand from boost.org, MinGW in not supported, that is, if Boost library (or program using Boost) is compiled with MinGW, then it is unstable.
Is it correct?
If it is, then what is going on with bitcoin (it is compiled on Windows with MinGW)?

**Link**
http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_55_0/more/getting_started/windows.html#pch

**Excerpt from the link**
"A note to Cygwin and MinGW users

If you plan to use your tools from the Windows command prompt, you're in the right place. If you plan to build from the Cygwin bash shell, you're actually running on a POSIX platform and should follow the instructions for getting started on Unix variants. Other command shells, such as MinGW's MSYS, are not supported—they may or may not work."

Thanks in advance,
--- Kosta

Answer (score 1):

Only MinGW's **MSYS** command shell is not supported.

**MSYS** is a collection of GNU utilities such as bash, make, gawk and grep to allow building of applications and programs which depend on traditionally UNIX tools to be present. It is intended to supplement MinGW and the "deficiencies" of the cmd shell.

BUT you can build Boost library with `MinGW` and `b2` under the standard Windows `cmd.exe` command prompt.

With MinGW installed and paths correctly set, usually these two commands are enough:

- `bootstrap.bat mingw`
- `b2 threading=multi toolset=gcc`

Once you have the libraries you can use them under the MSYS environment.